# Xamarin.forms : Display partial of next and previous view in carouselpage

Tags: xamarin.forms

In our Xamarin.forms app, we are using 'CarouselView.FormsPlugin' nuget to display 
CarouselView. I want to partially display the next and previous page like below image..

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the answer, I am also facing the same issue